# Receiving an error on flutter build appbundle

Tags: flutter, dart

Once I run "flutter build appbundle", I receive this error.

> Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseResources'. A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable Android resource linking failed ERROR:/Users/guy/Documents/Flutter Projects/newrealestate254rent/build/app/intermediates/bundle_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml:2: AAPT: error: attribute 'package' in  tag is not a valid Android package name: 'com.254rent.realestate'.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are having a problem in your Android Manifest.xml file. Please share the screenshot of that file.

Because the error you are getting is "error: attribute 'package' in tag is not a valid Android package name:"

Comment: @FaizanDarwesh I have attached the screenshot

Comment: Just make sure that you are using com.example.254rentrealestate as package name instead of 'com.254rent.realestate'. that shows in the error.

Comment: Please find in your whole code ''com.254rent.realestate' from where the compiler get this wrong package name.